# AWS python lambda datadog integration

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, datadog, aws-lambda-layers

I have a lambda written in python and I want to submit some custom metrics from the lambda to datadog

I followed this documentation, (https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/datadog-lambda-layer/) Added datadog dependencies as a lambda layer and added it to my lambda as a layer. When I test the lambda I receive the below error,

```
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'datadog_lambda'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "stackTrace": []
}

Function Logs
START RequestId: 63addc4a-389b-4526-865e-b44bc272f1ab Version: $LATEST
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'datadog_lambda'
```

Can anyone help me with figuring out the issue here.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score -4):

I assume that your lambda python script name is datadog_lambda.py. Then you need to change your lambda function handler name. Default handler name in lambda console is "lambda_function.lambda_handler". lambda_function is the default file name in Lambda. So change the handler to datadog_lambda.lambda_handler.

You can change the handler name from the Runtime settings pane.

From AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-handler.html)

```
A function handler can be any name; however, the default name in the Lambda 
console is lambda_function.lambda_handler. This function handler name reflects 
the function name (lambda_handler) and the file where the handler code is 
stored (lambda_function.py).
```

[image]